# Ordered list from pulling together words of the same class

Tags: javascript, html

On one of my web pages, I have a reading text with vocabulary words highlighted in green `(<span class="highlighted">)`.  I'm trying to write a script that takes all of these vocabulary words and puts them into an ordered list under the text.The code I wrote almost does exactly what I want, but it only displays the first letter of each list item. Here's what I have so far:

```
<ol id="vocabulary">
</ol>

<script>
//Get number of vocabulary terms
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('highlighted').length;
var listed = "";

//Pull each word out
for (var i =0; i < list; i++) {
    var vocab = document.getElementsByClassName('highlighted')[i].innerHTML
    //Create a new list item for each word
    listed += "<li>" + vocab[i]+ "</li>";
}

document.getElementById("vocabulary").innerHTML = listed;

</script>
```

Any ideas on how to do this?  Thank you!

Comment: please add something with highlighted class. other than this, vocab[i] inside for loop will always take ith char from that string.

Comment: change `vocab=docu....` to `vocab.push(docume....` and initialize `vocab = []`

Answer (score 5):

Because you are accessing the innerHTML's `i` element here `vocab[i]`. Try to do this.

```html
<ol id="vocabulary">
</ol>

<p class="highlighted">AAA</p>
<p class="highlighted">BBB</p>
<p class="highlighted">CCC</p>

<script>

var list = document.getElementsByClassName('highlighted');
var listed = "";

for (var i =0; i < list.length; i++) {
    listed += "<li>" + list[i].innerHTML + "</li>";
}

document.getElementById("vocabulary").innerHTML = listed;

</script>
```

Comment: Oh, wow...stupid mistake on my part.  Thank you, Suren!  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Quin if this helped you, please accept it to help others find it easily